# Launcher disappeared, how do I restore it?

Tags: launcher, adw.launcher

I mistakenly dragged an icon on the home screen (Nexus One) to the bottom area ("Main dock") that contains 3 main icons (phone, launcher, browser).

That icon replaced the launcher and now I can't access any of my other apps.

(My launcher is the ADWLauncher, that comes with CyganogenMod).

What do I do now?

How do I revert this back?

(I tried "Restore ADW settings" but unfortunately there was nothing in the backup location).

Is there a way to "restore it to factory settings"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`, find the launcher, and Clear Data for it.  Hopefully that will restore it to default.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. (I had to switch from the Downloaded to All first)

Comment: Great!  You can click the big checkmark to the left to mark this as the accepted answer if that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me too, and a simple `Power off` then `Power on` solved the problem.

(if one could avoid clearing data, this is even better)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a launcher app shortcut on the desktop (long press on the desktop then shortcuts; or something like that, can't remember the exact menu), then drag the launcher to the middle button. I've also often had this as well, accidentally removing the launcher shortcut every time I want to delete the shortcut, it's part of the reason I no longer uses ADW.